# How can I increase the size of the lines in a line chart using the asp.net mvc 3 razor web helper chart?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, charts, razor

I've currently got an application written in C#/mvc3/razor that uses a line chart that uses the system.web.helpers namespace.  The lines themselves are quite narrow and too small to be useful.  Does anyone know of any way to increase the width of the lines?

Addendum - to clarify - I am not using the  System.Web.UI.DataVisualization name space, but rather the System.Web.Helpers Namespace.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure its possible. The web helper charts are extremely limited in what they let you customize. I switched to System.Web.UI.DataVisualization instead.

Comment: It looks like that's what I'm going to have to do.  It seems that System.Web.Helpers isn't even close to being ready.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find a list of custom properties [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456764.aspx)

I had to use charting controls in MVC-3 few months ago. Unfortunately helpers supported very little, so I had to modify properties through [Series.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456700.aspx)

**Edit:** This is my original question.